# Get array value Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to pass a value to the form, but for some reason in `index.blade` I see the array that it is full, and for `form.blade` for some reason the array is empty.

In form.blade I want to shove all the already selected value from the array into iput and then update the information. What happen ?

SystemController

```
class SystemController extends Controller{



    public function index(){
        return view('admin.options.index',[
            'options' => DB::table('systems')->first(),
        ]);
    }


    public function edit(System $system){
        return view('admin.options.edit',[
            'array' => $system,

        ]); 
    }

    public function update(Request $request,System $system){
        $system->update($request->except('id'));
        /*$last_row = DB::table('systems')->latest()->first();*/
        $system->first_column = $request['first_column'];
        $system->second_column = $request['second_column'];
        $system->third_column = $request['third_column'];
        // $system->update($last_row); 
        $system->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.options.index');
    }
```

index.blade

```
<tbody>
<?php $array = json_decode(json_encode($options), true); ?>
<?php var_dump($array) ?>
    <tr>
      <td>{{$array['first_column'] ?? ""}}</td>
      <td>{{$array['first_column'] ?? ""}}</td>
      <td>{{$array['first_column'] ?? ""}}</td>
      <td class="text-right">

          <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('admin.options.edit', $array)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

`var_dump` get

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["first_column"]=> string(13) "
dsfdsf

" ["second_column"]=> string(15) "
dsfsfdsf

" ["third_column"]=> string(13) "
dsfdsf

" }
```

edit.blade.php

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.options.update', $array)}}" method="post" >
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
  {{ csrf_field() }}

  {{-- Form include --}}

 @include('admin.options.partials.form')

</form>
```

form.blade.php

```
<?php var_dump($array) // get All null  ?>
```

Comment: How are you initializing `$array` in edit?

Comment: @El_Vanja this is all my code that i use

Comment: In `index` you have this: `<?php $array = json_decode(json_encode($options), true); ?>`. You're not doing anything like that in `edit`?

Comment: @El_Vanja no, I’m not doing anything like that. `<?php $array = json_decode(json_encode($options), true); ?>` if I write like this, it displays an error about a nonexistent variable `options`

Comment: Of course, because `$options` aren't defined in `edit`. I was just checking to see if you were reformatting in any way that could result in a null value. Can you show your include code then?

Comment: all the code that I use, I already set

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($array)` inside of `edit`?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, return ALL NULL